# What's the difference between Normal mode and Hard?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I have noticed that you can choose between Normal and Hard at the start of a run in The Binding of Isaac: Rebirth. What changes when you choose Hard?

Comment: I still haven't had time to experiment, but on my first two plays on Normal, the game feels easier than the "Vanilla" version of The Binding of Isaac - I wonder if the Hard mode has a similar difficulty to that version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned [here](http://bindingofisaac.com/post/98202531689/isaac-the-hardening) by Ed, some effects are no heart drops from bosses and curses being more prevalent.

I'd hazard to guess that less drops in general and higher HP enemies might play a part. Especially less drops.

And here's his general notes copied over from the linked post:

- Beating different goals in Hard mode will unlock new content not unlockable on Normal.
- Beating said goals in Hard mode will also unlock any unlocks that would be gained by beating Normal mode (so you can start on hard if you’d like)
- There will be achievements for Hard mode.
- Hard mode will have some visual hud/menu changes so you are always aware if you are playing on Hard. (or watching someone play on Hard)

Comment: Thank you for the link! This answer can be improved for other people if you edit in Ed's notes that are included on his post (regarding achievements and unlocks).

Comment: Oh by the way, "some effects are no heart drops from bosses" is something Ed said, but isn't true in the least.