# Binding Of Isaac Rebirth, Red Icon

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

[image: screenshot]

I have encountered this, wondering what it is, never picked up anything just randomed character, simple run

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are playing on Hard, probably selected it inadvertently on the character select screen. It's easy to choose it accidentally because it's selected via the up/down arrows/sticks.

Comment: Already figured it out when lost ))

Answer (score 2):

> **The red icon means your playing in hard mode.**

It is very easy to mis-click the button and go to hard mode, so you have to be on the look out if your not ready for the immense difficulty.

**Why people play on Hard Mode:**

> There is a "hard mode" for more experienced players, giving away a few new rewards that are unattainable in other difficulties.

**What is different in the Hard Mode vs. Normal Mode:**

> **1.** Beating different goals in Hard mode will unlock new content not unlockable on Normal.
>
> **2.** Beating said goals in Hard mode will also unlock any unlocks that would be gained by beating Normal mode (so you can start on hard if you’d like)
>
> **3.** There will be achievements for Hard mode.
>
> **4.** Hard mode will have some visual hud/menu changes so you are always aware if you are playing on Hard. (or watching someone play on Hard)

**You can see where you click to get into Hard Mode here:**

[image]

[Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190633/whats-the-difference-between-normal-mode-and-hard)

[Source 2](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/The_Binding_of_Isaac:_Rebirth)